# Defining an output file stream within a class

Tags: c++, class, fstream

How can I define an output file stream within a class, so that I don't have to keep passing it around to functions. Basically what I want to do is this:

```
class A {

private:
   ofstream otp ;

};
```

Then in my constructor, I simply have `otp.open("myfile");` and in other functions I have `otp.open("myfile", ios::app);` , but it fails during compile time, saying:

```
../thermo.h(18): error: identifier "ofstream" is undefined
      ofstream otp ;
```

I have made sure to `#include <fstream>`

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's not such a big deal to keep redefining `ofstream` in each of my functions`... Was just wondering if what I'm trying to do is possible, probably for curiosity sake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the fully qualified name, `std::ofstream`.

Comment: Worked! Excellent. thank you. Would you mind giving a small explanation why I needed to do that even when I `use namespace std` ?

Comment: @Amit: if you put `using namespace std` in a module *after* the includes (where it should go!), then the declaration is not yet in effect when the header is parsed.

Comment: Hmm... I'm a little confused, basically I'm `#including` a header file that contains includes to many things, one of them being `<fstream>`, etc. At the end of the includes, it has `using namespace std`. Therefore, I can use `cout` and other `std::` functions in all of my functions that include this `global header file`. Then howcome I had to explicitly either declare `std::ofstream` or add an additional `using namespace std` below my `#include "globals.h"` ?

Comment: @Amit: *Would you mind giving a small explanation why I needed to do that even when I `use namespace std` ?* The best thing to do is to get out of the habit of `use namespace std;` It takes only five extra characters to type the correct name without using that using directive. Once you get into the habit of specifying the full name you won't go back. Using the full name adds clarity to the code and keeps you out of big trouble. In particular, putting `use namespace std;` in a header file will eventually get you in big, big trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You need either place a `using namespace std;` statement above your class's declaration or declare the `otp` variable as `std::ofstream` because it exists within the `std` namespace.

Comment: Please don't tell people that putting `using namespace std` in a header is an option.

Comment: What if I `include "globals.h"`, where `globals.h` has `using namespace std;` in it? How come that doesn't translate into my `thermo.h` file ?

Comment: @Amit Are you sure that `using namespace std;` isn't in some other scope (`namespace`, function)?

Comment: @Amit: Do **NOT** place `using namespace XXX` inside a header file. You will really piss off other developers when they try and use your code. As your code is now negatively effecting their code. Only place `using namespace XXX` in source files where it helps you but will not break other peoples code.